# How to rotate scene via python script?

Tags: python, scene

I'm super new to Blender and working on a script for Blender. My question is how to rotate scene via python script, just like using middle mouse?

Thank you.

Comment: Would look at MMB more akin to orbiting our focus point in  the scene.  ([see view matrix](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_matrix)). Think of the scene as the basis of global coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to batFINGER I've found the answer

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Euler

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_rotation.rotate(Euler((0, 0, 0.01)))
```